# Flow running as System gives Insufficient Privileges

Tags: visual-workflow

My flow is set to run as System Context - without sharing.

I am running it in debug mode, setting the running user as say user A.
Through the flow, an Opportunity belonging to user B will be updated.
Opportunity OWD is Private.

I get Insufficient Privileges error when the flow runs. But isn't the flow suppossed to modify all data irrespective of sharing rules, as I chose that System Context setting?

Comment: Can you check the user A has permission to run the flow.? at user level you have  "flow User" checkbox permission needs to be checked.

Comment: thank you for your comment. yes he has. this flow has many other functionalities as well that work fine when ran as user A. Only when the new logic to update another person's Opp was added, it started to fail.